# Encourage users to use SharePoint.StackExchange instead of posting on SO

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, subdomains

There is a dedicated [SharePoint.StackExchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) and yet users post their questions on Stack Overflow. Is there a way to encourage people to use SharePoint.StackExchange instead of Stack Overflow or advertise SharePoint.StackExchange to the users as they might not even know?

Comment: If you see recent questions, you can always flag them for migration like "belongs to another SE site"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the tagwiki states that [Sharepoint questions have another, more appropriate home](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172308/199700) (as stated by Danny Beckett), it's also good to point such information out in comments if one happens upon such a question.

There's a remarkable disregard for what's written in tagwikis, in my experience, which is why I sometimes leave a friendly message that, while not entirely off-topic, they might have better luck at X or Y with their specific question.

Answer (score 4):

The tag-wiki excerpt for [sharepoint](/questions/tagged/sharepoint) already begins:

> For SharePoint-specific questions, please see the SharePoint Stack Exchange (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com) site.

I don't really see how that could be improved upon...